# How to survive the remaining 5 months of my postdoc in toxic environment?

Tags: postdocs, interpersonal-issues, international-students

I am international postdoc and 7 months into my 1 year postdoc. My PI is very young and the lab is relatively new. I chose this lab because after the interview I was convinced that the PI and I had similar research interests. I had also made sure the work would be experimental in nature since that is what I am an expert in.

The research direction proposed seemed interesting and I have enjoyed working on the project. But there is a major mismatch between our attitudes. I do appreciate him taking the time out to listen to my research plan and goals but I just cannot bear the abusive nature of the PI. In my 6 months time he has humiliated me in front of the whole group twice (both for journal clubs), saying my presentations should be much better than what it is. The theoretical aspect of my work is not of my interest and he expects me to know each and everything about it even though it's a new topic for me. There is zero tolerance for any mistake or unanswered question.

Long story short, I feel under-confident and bullied I am convinced that I need to look for a new position and have already started contacting some potential advisers (no luck yet).

My questions are the following:

1. How do I survive the remaining 5 months of my postdoc with an
   abusive mentor who has unreasonably high standards?
2. I have been so stressed since the past month that I feel unfit for
   any position. How do I regain my confidence?
3. How do I find a position without a reference letter from the current
   adviser?

Comment: Have you talked to other people at your university? I would recommend seeking out someone local to talk to about the situation: other postdocs in your lab, the department chair, the university ombudsman (if one exists), the international student services office (if one exists).

Comment: I am the only postdoc in the lab and the PI comes across as a very nice person in general. I am the only one facing the brunt so i won't blame them if they find it hard to believe. My labmates are not interactive too. I haven't yet approached the international student services yet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If your university or your healthcare plan offers access to a therapist, find one. If you cannot leave yet, they can at least help you sort through this situation and distance yourself emotionally a little, so that you will be less impacted by your PI's attitude.

Comment: @nengel Yes, i am considering therapy. Hopefully that should help me through this rought time. Thank you!

Comment: About 3) Did you actually asked for a reference letter? The attitude of the PI can be hard to read, and he could accept to write you (good) letters of recommendation. About 2) Talk to your previous co-authors, mentors, and colleagues. Mention without stressing the current situation, and engage in future collaborations, if that is an option. For 1) Hold on! Don't be isolated, discuss with other people in the department and avoid your PI if that's an option.

Comment: 1) Is it only you that gets a harsh treatment in journal club? Perhaps it is just the PI's style, and you should not take it as a sign of the PI's opinion of you. In my department, we ask very tough questions and criticize a lot during internal presentations because our philosophy is that you want your friends to be your worst critics (so all future presentations seem easy!).

Comment: 2) How do you know the reference letter will not be good? I know people who receive good letters from professors that are also occasionally very critical. The best tactic to take with those professors is "Thank you so much for the criticism, it is really helping to make me better." When someone improves because of my criticism, I tend to think well of them, not poorly.

Comment: Your question didn't convince me that you are in a toxic environment. It might just be a clash of different cultures combined with lack of open communication. I'm just putting this out here because (1) others (potential future advisors) might see it similarly, and (2) it might be something that could be fixed. Just my two cents after reading the question; maybe it's a useful perspective.

Comment: Talk to Human Resources, they should then point you to the right people to get this resolved. They may also give their opinion on your situation.

Comment: In response to others, I do think it is a bad environment (I'm not sure I would say toxic). Personal criticism should not be made in front of others, which is why it humiliates the victim. Stating a presentation should be much better than it is, is non-constructive. It is just a statement to put someone down. Stating what could improve a presentation is perfectly fine in front of others, that is constructive feedback. This is why I suggest the original poster talks to HR, they should help delineate between criticism and abuse.

Comment: @Clément Thank you for commenting. About 1) I never asked for a reference letter. About 1) and 2) thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @Dawn About 1) While it is true that he is a tough mentor, it is only me who gets a "harsh" treatment with statements like- The presentations are not "postdoc standard" and that "you cannot have a postdoc setting a wrong example for grad students" in public. About 2) This is exactly what I am doing right now although I don't think he appreciates any improvements i make ( I maybe wrong, it's difficult to tell). Thank you for the comments!

Comment: @Roland I agree it might not come across as 'toxic" and i do agree with your perspective. The only reason i called it toxic was because this has been going on from very early on. There have been many instances of nit-picking which was far from constructive criticism but more on belittling me. The constructive criticism part comes in only when i ask for it in the following one on one meeting. I am trying my best to reduce the clashes and patiently trying to salvage the situation. Thank you for the comments

Comment: @ThomasKing I agree calling this "toxic" might be wrong. It is definitely  a bad environment because over time it is just counter-productive. It's more like a power play and me getting intimidated with the constant thought in my mind " will he yell at me again in public". Maybe all i need is to develop a thick skin, shrug it off and focus on improving my situation here. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @Ahmsherg if he is yelling at you in public (or in general, especially over a period of time), then I think HR would view this as bullying.

Comment: After 6 months I would expect a post-doc to have a firm grasp of all aspects of a project (even those that for whatever reason don't interest you).

Comment: @JonCuster Even if that means I am a bad postdoc, it should be pointed out to me when i go in for a one on one meeting and try to get his feedback.  Maybe i am not suitable for the pace with which a postdoc should grasp new topics (something for me to think about).

Comment: @JonCuster We probably have a different understanding of what "all aspects of a project" means, but in three post-doc, I never thought that I understood more than a tenth of the projects I was involved in after a year of full work. I guess the scope and the scale of the project depends with the topic / matter / field.

Comment: @Amsherg Sad story, glad you asked. Try yoga and meditation. In case you had anxiety issues, I suggest you to visit this website: https://www.anxietybc.com/

Answer (score 8):

Although I may not have stood in your shoes as a post doctoral scholar, however I hope I can give you some insight on the behavior of your PI.

> How do I survive the remaining 5 months of my postdoc with an abusive mentor who has unreasonably high standards?

First and foremost, don't take it personally.

If your PI is for lack of a better word an a**. I doubt there is anything you can do to change that. On the other hand, what you can control is your perception and acceptance of such negative behavior.

Peeling back the emotional layers, is there truth to what is being said? Is there a fundamental misunderstanding on your part of a given subject matter? For example, if your PI berates you in public on not knowing that 1+1=2, you can approach the problem from two (among many) views. One is emotion: your PI just humiliated you in front of your peers. The other is the core issue at hand, knowledge, does 1+1 really equal 2?

With emotion: you can perceive it with the desired emotion or you can dust it off with nonchalance. Reply stoically "I didn't know that, thank you for pointing it out to me". Address the outburst and move on.

If you don't let hate (and in this case, a severe lack of tact on part of your PI) get to you, it robs the abuser of their satisfaction (if it was intentional). If it wasn't intentional, then it is a rather rocky learning process for your PI as one day, when their supervisor (or senior faculty) sees this going on, they will get their a** chewed out for humiliating their people or find themselves without anyone who is willing to work it them, effectively being an academic pariah. (Yeah he/she is smart, but he/she is a pain to work with, let's not).

With knowledge: it will be up to you to determine if you are in fact, in the wrong. If so, adapt your understanding with newfound knowledge and move on. If you are wrong, you are wrong, there isn't much more to discuss. If you are right... well... ask yourself if it is worth the battle to prove to a belligerent PI that they are incorrect.

> I have been so stressed since the past month that I feel unfit for any position. How do I regain my confidence?

Take a moment and look at all of the struggles that you've accomplished and overcome thus far. Your graduate tests, qualification exams, writing a dissertation, defending you thesis, buying your review board's favorite foods, for the last >4 years of your life. Putting up with an a**hole for the next 5 months in comparison is a drop in the bucket.

Keep your eyes forward on the goals you've set for yourself and what kept you going all these years.

> How do I find a position without a reference letter from the current adviser?

My understanding of a reference letter, is to have someone who is knowledgeable of your work ethic, vouch for you. I believe there would be more than your PI whom you've worked closely with this past year. A faculty member perhaps?

Comment: About 1) There is a lack of understanding on the theoretical part of the work which is not my strong suite and that is the only section I am berated for. I do not question his criticism, my only issue is none of my misgivings are addressed in the one on one meeting. It is only in group meetings and my presentations where it is put across to me that I need to know more than I do on the current subject matter. I am trying my best to deal with it  by reading and taking some online courses. About 3) I do have good letters from my Master's and Graduate school PI's.

Comment: (1) If there was one thing I've learned about interpersonal relationships, it is to praise in public and criticise in private. Although you can bring this up to the PI, it might be a futile endeavor. One day your PI would find themselves without anyone who is willing to work for or with them. (3) then that will suffice. Keep in touch with them and move on.

Comment: (1) In addition to criticizing in public, he once casually joked with a grad student that if he doesnt get a funding soon he will be firing me! And this was less than 4 months of my joining. Anyway the list is long, but i will try my best to improve the situation from side (3) Hope it works!